# Drawing attention to my Careers page

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I've created a profile on Stack Overflow Careers, and I've made it public and opened to search engines. I've defined all of the technologies I can work with. I created it last Friday. It is Tuesday today and in profile stats I see only zeroes: no one saw my profile.

What can I do to draw prospective employers' attention to my profile?

Comment: While I'm sure there are things you can do to draw more attention (so the question remains valid): it's been less than a week; I'd give it some time before I got too worried.

Comment: Is this question an attempt to get us all to visit your profile? Hmm... let me put on my tinfoil hat!

Comment: Hmm, you want a future employer to visit your 104 reputation profile with 0 answers and questions only? I'm not sure if that's a good idea. But since I could not find your Careers profile, I can't tell much about it. Perhaps your profile is much better than your activity.

Comment: Make your profile picture interesting. I find that I'm more likely to view peoples' profiles to get a better look at their profile picture.

Comment: Stack Overflow Careers is probably not among the most popular job sites. In ~2 years I've had 9 views, and one enquiry.

Comment: @Stryner well, RIP my chances at any vegetarian company :/

Answer (score 28):

You could enable the "Stack Overflow Careers Profile" button to show in your main site profile; perhaps small, but certainly worth it.

It's in "Edit Profile & Settings" -> "Edit Profile" -> "Web presence".

Comment: I can't find this. Is it on each SE website or on Careers website?

Comment: @A.L I found it in my Stack Overflow settings.

Comment: OK I see it, I was lost because it's only named *Settings* on this meta website.

Comment: My goodness, I have been looking for a job, and I thought I was visible, and it turns out that I wasn't.  Thanks for this info.  My suggestion to SO Careers is that this setting, and the way it is presented, (or rather, *hidden*,) is a ***major*** usability issue.

Answer (score 11):

Although it may not be the reply you wish to have... increasing your reputation or showing your expertise in a specific technology (top users in the tag page) will likely draw attention to your Career Profile.

Of course, it takes time and effort.

Answer (score 8):

You could include a link to such a profile in applications, email correspondence, etc. with relevant companies or individuals. Direct interactions in other words.

Presumably, employers who preferably search SO Careers, will find you anyway, while employers who preferably search for certain skills will find many similar sites.